# Python loop for constructing an increasingly longer function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

My code follows the following pattern for any number of days.. Is there any way of making some sort of loop to simplify it without having to hardcode every single case? I have to write about 400 of these lines without a loop.

```
if dia == 0: mapa[dia] = mapa[dia]
if dia == 1: mapa[dia] = mapa[dia].subtract(mapa[0])   
if dia == 2: mapa[dia] = mapa[dia].subtract(mapa[0]).subtract(mapa[1])
if dia == 3: mapa[dia] = mapa[dia].subtract(mapa[0]).subtract(mapa[1]).subtract(mapa[2])
if dia == 4: mapa[dia] = mapa[dia].subtract(mapa[0]).subtract(mapa[1]).subtract(mapa[2]).subtract(mapa[3])
if dia == 5: mapa[dia] = mapa[dia].subtract(mapa[0]).subtract(mapa[1]).subtract(mapa[2]).subtract(mapa[3]).subtract(mapa[4])
if dia == 6: mapa[dia] = mapa[dia].subtract(mapa[0]).subtract(mapa[1]).subtract(mapa[2]).subtract(mapa[3]).subtract(mapa[4]).subtract(mapa[5])
```

Comment: You can apply [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with slicing.

Comment: Prefect question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `reduce` , or a simple forloop will do the trick

```
for i in range(dia):
    mapa[dia] = mapa[dia].subtract(mapa[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Olvin Roght's suggestion, the [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) variant would be:

```
mapa[dia] = reduce(function = lambda x, y: x.substract(y), 
                   iterable = [mapa[dia]] + [mapa[n] for n in range(0, dia)]])
```

We can either provide an iterable that starts with `mapa[dia]` then follows with all the numbers, or use the `initializer` argument which is great when the first element of the operations does not follow the same order as the next ones. The latter case is nice because we can use a generator rather than a hand-built list and free up some memory.

```
mapa[dia] = reduce(function = lambda x, y: x.substract(y),
                   iterable = (mapa[n] for n in range(0, dia)),
                   initializer = mapa[dia])
```

Here, the first `x` is `mapa[dia]` and the first `y` is `mapa[0]`, then the next `x` is `mapa[dia].substract(mapa[0])` and the next `y` is `mapa[1]`, etc...

Now we need to benchmark which approach of `reduce` or a `for` loop is faster.

Comment: This is very helpful. It is the first time I have managed to understand the reduce function. Thank you.

Comment: Me too! Trying to answer you motivated me to take a look at how it works. Glad it helps :)

Comment: @Guimoute, you can also slice list `mapa[:dia]` or use [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) if you don't want to create temporary list *(imho, generator looks a bit weird there)*.